# @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) and the content_type is not added to header in uber jar

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-17, hk2

I am so confusing.

There is an Jakarta application that is run by GrizzlyHttpServer and the following configuration:

1- JDK 17

2- hibernate 5

3- hk2 for DI

The pom.xml is :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey DI and core-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-metadata-generator</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- add jackson as json provider -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this to hide warning for jakarta.activation.DataSource -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- test json data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <version>${jsonassert.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.12.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.art.vesal</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.behsa</groupId>
            <artifactId>behsa-utils</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.freeutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcharset</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ir.ghasemkiani</groupId>
            <artifactId>persiancalendar</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
            <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.org.jdom</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.art</groupId>
            <artifactId>dataserver_api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jodd</groupId>
            <artifactId>jodd-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

and the Jersey endpoint is :

```
@Path("/backend")
public class MessageRelayRest {

    @Inject
    private UserDaoInf log;
    @Inject
    private ArtMTSMSRemoteInf relay;

    @Path("/many2many")
    @POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ReferenceResultModel sendMessageManyToMany(MessageRelayModel messageRelayModel) {
        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
        ReferenceResultModel result = relay.sendMessageManyToMany(messageRelayModel.getUsername(), messageRelayModel.getPassword(), messageRelayModel.getOriginator(), messageRelayModel.getDestination(), messageRelayModel.getContent(), messageRelayModel.getUserSuppliedIds(), messageRelayModel.getIp());
        return result;
    }

.....
```

Everything is working correctly as expected in Intellij IDEA but when I make as uber jar by the following maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>
                                        com.art.vesal.MainApp
                                    </mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

and run the jar by `java -jar`, when request to the endpoint, the following error is raised:

> POST http://localhost:8081/backend/many2many returned a response
> status of 415 Unsupported Media Type
>
> 14-Nov-2022 15:58:36.811 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-78]
> com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity A message body
> reader for Java class com.art.vesal.common.model.ReferenceResultModel,
> and Java type class com.art.vesal.common.model.ReferenceResultModel,
> and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found 14-Nov-2022
> 15:58:36.812 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-78]
> com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity The registered
> message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
> application/octet-stream ->
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider
> */* ->   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
> com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
> com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader

Where is wrong? I am so confusing!!

**EDIT 1**
This is main class:

```
public class MainApp {

    public static final URI BASE_URI = URI.create("http://localhost:8081");

    // Starts Grizzly HTTP server
    public static HttpServer startHttpServer() {

        final ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
        config.register(MessageRelayRest.class);
        config.register(CustomJacksonMapperProvider.class);
        config.register(CustomJsonExceptionMapper.class);
        config.register(Binder.class);
        // JacksonFeature for JAXB/POJO, for pure JSON, no need this JacksonFeature
        // config.register(JacksonFeature.class);

        return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, config);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            final HttpServer server = startHttpServer();

            server.start();

            // shut down hook
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(server::shutdownNow));

            System.out.println(String.format("Application started.%nStop the application using CTRL+C"));

            // block and wait shut down signal, like CTRL+C
            Thread.currentThread().join();

        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
            //Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: error means you are not passing proper request it should be json of MessageRelayModel
how are you calling backend

Comment: If you are right, why it is correct in Intellij idea??

Comment: My guess would be you need to use the appending accumulator when creating the uber jar.  The files under META-INF/hk2-locator need to be appended to each other when creating your uber jar, rather than replacing each other.  There is some documentation somewhere under hk2 about how to do this.  I'll see if I can find it later but that's probably the issue